# Conjugation in $GL(V)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, automorphism-group

Given $T,P\in GL(V)$, what does it mean to conjugate $T^{-1}PT$? I understand that if we choose a basis for $V$, then conjugation on $GL_n(F)$ just becomes representing the same linear transformation under different choices of basis. However, it seems to me that conjugation in $GL(V)$ is different because if it were the same, we'd be saying $T^{-1}PT=P$ which is definitely false. However, $GL_n(F)$ and $GL(V)$ are isomorphic as groups which further confuses me. Could anyone shed some insight?

Answer (score 0):

The word *conjugate* can have several meanings depending on the context, even restricted to the scope of your question.

1. First, in abstract algebra, an entity such as $$T^{-1}PT$$
   is called the *conjugate* of $P$ by $T$. This terminology holds in any group. One will say that a group (here $GL(V)$) *acts on itself by conjugation*.
2. Completely unrelated, some people use the word *conjugate* to refer to the matrix $M^*$ of the adjoint operator, when the vector space $V$ is endowed with an inner product.
3. Finally, when the base field is $\Bbb C$, the *conjugate* of a matrix can refer to the matrix $\bar M$ obtained by applying complex conjugation to every entry.

---

Now I believe that your question is about the first definition. It is true that $T^{-1}PT$ represents the same operator (call it $L$) as $P$ but in a different basis. **That does not make $T^{-1}PT$ equal to $P$ as a matrix**.  For the same input vector $\vec v$ would have different coordinates and correspond to a different column-vector depending on whether you want to use the matrix $P$ or the matrix $T^{-1}PT$ to compute the output $L(\vec v)$.

Comment: I understand as matrices these are definitely different. My problem is operators are defined without respect to any basis, so in my mind it should be true that $T^{-1} PT=P$ because they are literally the same operators, if conjugation is GL(V) is literally the same as conjugation in GL_n(F) . But we have a problem because operators don't commute in general. So I'm wondering where my mistake in thinking is.

Comment: @PaulT To view a matrix as an operator, you need to specify a basis. $P$ and $T^{-1}PT$ are the same operator only with different bases, so that the same input looks different to them. That's what I wrote after the boldface sentence; I think that it answers exactly your question.

Comment: I do understand what you're saying, but the point I'm trying to make is I I want to eliminate bases/matrices out of the discussion and view $T,P$ as abstract operators which take in vectors $v$ without specifying a basis. I believe that this viewpoint is legal, because its core, linear operators are ultimately functions which don't require a coordinate system $(v\mapsto Tv)$. So as abstract transformations, to my understanding, they take in the same $v$ and output the same vector $Tv$.